# dependenacy libraries when installing svgcairo

Tags: linux, haskell, cabal, glib, cairo

I want to run a Setup.hs file to install svgcairo library, So I run first the command `runhaskell Setup.hs configure --prefix=/usr/local` but it's give me the following error : 
`Configuring svgcairo-0.13.0.1...
setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
cairo >=0.13.0.0 && <0.14, glib >=0.13.0.0 && <0.14`
 
This is confused me, since both cairo and glib are installed with the correct versions ! 
to make it convince, I have run the commands `cabal install cairo` and `cabal install glib`, and the following output appear: 
 
 `Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
cairo-0.13.0.6
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.`

`Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
glib-0.13.0.7
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.`


Note : I tried to run the Setup.hs file with `runhaskell Setup.hs` but its tell me that `no command given (try --help)`

Comment: Why are you using `runhaskell Setup.hs configure` rather than `cabal configure`? The latter is quite a bit more clever when it comes to setting package db paths; in particular if any sandboxes are involved.

Comment: @kosmikus actually I dont know haskell but I have to use it for installing a driver, I have work with your suggestions, and it's give me the following output : ` `SetupWrapper.hs:12:39:
    Module
    ` ` Distribution.Simple.Configure'
    does not export
    `configCompilerEx'
` ,

Answer (score 1):

`cabal install` defaults to installing to the local package database. `Setup.hs` defaults to installing to the global package database (hence will ignore anything installed in the local package database when trying to satisfy dependencies). You can change the behavior of either by passing `--local` or `--global` to the appropriate stage -- `configure` for `Setup.hs`, and `configure` or `install` for `cabal`.